# Why Firefox in Linux have a title bar by default?

Tags: firefox, desktop

In Windows and macOS, Firefox have its title bar hidden by default, but I am curious to know why Firefox have its title bar visible by default in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't for me.  I tested creating a new Firefox profile, and it doesn't show a separate titlebar.  (I know I can enable the titlebar if I want).

It is mentioned in the release notes for Firefox version 66. (Note: I use Gnome).

> [System title bar is hidden by default to match Gnome guideline for Linux users](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/66.0/releasenotes/)

I'm not sure what the internet is telling me about Firefox on KDE. Maybe something enabled the Firefox titlebar on your system, in an attempt to avoid a bug.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox/Tweaks#Hide_only_title_bar_in_KDE

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1453386